# error: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

The below code:

```
#include <cstddef>
using std::size_t;

int hOccupy(int* numB, const void* f, int bS, size_t dyn);

template <class T>
inline int hOccupy(int* numB, T f, int bS, size_t dyn) {
    return hOccupy(numB, reinterpret_cast<const void*>(f), bS, dyn);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    decltype(&hOccupy) f = &hOccupy;
}
```

gives the error:

```
 error: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?
```

Can anyone suggest what's wrong here and how to overcome it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hOccupy` is an overloaded function.  That means in order to get the address of it, you need to specify which overload you want the address of.  For instance, if you want the pointer to point to

```
hError_t hOccupy(int* numB, const void* f, int bS, size_t dyn);
```

then you can use

```
auto f = static_cast<hError_t (*)(int, const void*, int, size_t)>(&hOccupy);
```

---

If you want `f` to refer to the overload set, then you can do that using a lambda like

```
auto f = [](int* numB, auto f, int bS, size_t dyn){ return hOccupy(numB, f, bS, dyn); };
```

Comment: Could he just eliminate the first declaration, leaving the void* case to be covered by the templated declaration?

Comment: Or even `hError_t (*f)(int, const void*, int, size_t) = &hOccupy;`

Comment: @donjuedo It looks like template is a wrapper for the function so they don't have to cast what they pass for `f` to a `const void*`

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the answer.  I understand we need to specify which overload address we want.  But if i want to keep main() as it is, is there any other way to tweak the hoccupy function. is it possible.

Comment: @SatyanveshD There might be something, but it depends on what you want `f` to be.  What do you want it to point to?

Comment: You mean f to point to a certain type like int?? Is my understanding correct.

Comment: @SatyanveshD With `decltype(&hOccupy) f = &hOccupy;`, which version of `hOccupy` do you want `f` to point to?  How are you going to be using it?

Answer (score 2):

To complement the [answer provided by NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60096728/10871073), if you instead wanted a pointer to a *specific instance* of your template overload, you need to specify the type (T) in your code.

For example:

```cpp
decltype(&hOccupy<int*>) f = &hOccupy;
```

Without a specified type, your `decltype` statement is ill-formed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.